# Expose symbols to dynamic linker when linking with native library in Rust

Tags: rust, dynamic-linking, rust-cargo

I am building a binary executable in Rust and it needs to link to a native library, say `foo.a`. `foo.a` contains a symbol `void bar(void)`, which I would like to expose to the dynamic linker as a callback function that can be called by functions in a `dlopen`-style dynamically loaded library.

This can be done in `ld` by supplying `-rdynamic` if we use `C` source.

```
gcc -rdynamic -o a_dynamic main.c foo.c
```

What is the proper way of doing this in Rust? I have tried using `cargo:rustc-flags=-rdynamic` in `build.rs`, as well as

```
#![feature(link_args)]
#[link_args = "-rdynamic"]
```

Neither seems to work.

Comment: Just a wild guess - use `cargo:rustc-flags=-C link-args=-rdynamic`. Arguments to the linker are passed through `-C link-args` option in rustc.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Tried it. No luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, Rust toolchain discourages passing arbitrary flags to the linker. The closest we can do as a proper way is using `cargo rustc` and manually add the linking arguments.

```
cargo rustc -- -C link-args='-rdynamic'
```